# How can add unsubscribe link in custom email template magento1?

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates

I want to add `unsubscribe` link in the custom email template. I am using code:

`<a href="{{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}"><strong>Unsubscribe</strong></a>`

But it is not working, can anybody help to do this?

Comment: to use unsubscribe variable in custom email template you have to set it first from your code to send email

Answer (score 2):

You need to create custom variable and use in the custom email template.
for example:

```
$unsubscribeUrl = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->loadByEmail($email)->getUnsubscriptionLink();
$vars = array('quote' => $quote, 'url' => $url, 'customunsubscribeurl' => $unsubscribeUrl);
```

Now, You can use "customunsubscribeurl" in custom email template.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<a href="{{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}">
{{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}
</a>
```

Or you can try this also :

=> **Copy the core file**

> /app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php

**=> add in your local directory**

> /app/code/local/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php

replace code in `endConfirmationSuccessEmail()`

```
$email->sendTransactional(
    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_IDENTITY),
    $this->getEmail(),
    $this->getName(),
    array('subscriber'=>$this)
);
```

with

```
$email->sendTransactional(
    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_IDENTITY),
    $this->getEmail(),
    $this->getName(),
    array('subscriber'=>$this, 'unsubscribe' =>$this->getUnsubscriptionLink())
);
```

right this code where you want to add unsubscribe link :

```
<a href="{{var unsubscribe}}">Unsubscribe here</a>
```

It may be useful for you :)

Comment: Any other solution becouse I have tried this.

Comment: No sir, I have no other solution. I checked it and its working.

Comment: Can I use "unsubscribe" var  outside newsletter email template

Comment: Nop. It's not possible.